# Android Publisher: "Track names in request path and request body must match."

Tags: python, android, google-api, google-api-client, androidpublisher

I'm using the google-api-python-client library to upload apks to Google Playstore. All worked well until today. I did not modify my upload script but now i am getting the error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/[packageName]/edits/[editId]/tracks/internal?alt=json returned 
**"Track names in request path and request body must match."**
```

This is my upload script:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json
import mimetypes

package_name = '...'
keyfile_content = '...'
apk_file = '...'
release_name = '...'
track = 'internal'

mimetypes.add_type("application/octet-stream", ".apk")
mimetypes.add_type("application/octet-stream", ".aab")

keyfile_dict = json.loads(keyfile_content)
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(keyfile_dict, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher')
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', http=http)

edit_request = service.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package_name)
result = edit_request.execute()
edit_id = result['id']

apk_response = service.edits().apks().upload(
        editId=edit_id,
        packageName=package_name,
        media_body=apk_file).execute()

print('Version code %d has been uploaded but not yet committed' % apk_response['versionCode'])

if track:
    track_response = service.edits().tracks().update(
        editId=edit_id,
        track=track,
        packageName=package_name,
        body={u'releases': [{
            u'name': release_name,
            u'versionCodes': [str(apk_response['versionCode'])],
            u'status': u'completed',
        }]}).execute()

    print('Track %s is set with releases: %s' % (
        track_response['track'], str(track_response['releases'])))
else:
    print('No track specified')

commit_request = service.edits().commit(
        editId=edit_id, packageName=package_name).execute()

print('Edit "%s" has been committed' % commit_request['id'])
```

I am using google-api-python-client 1.7.11.

I could not find anything about the error online. Has anyone here an idea?

**Update**

Thanks to the [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60661500/11236760) from @Silvio i could get my script to work again by adding the track to the request body as well:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json
import mimetypes

package_name = '...'
keyfile_content = '...'
apk_file = '...'
release_name = '...'
track = 'internal'

mimetypes.add_type("application/octet-stream", ".apk")
mimetypes.add_type("application/octet-stream", ".aab")

keyfile_dict = json.loads(keyfile_content)
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(keyfile_dict, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher')
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', http=http)

edit_request = service.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package_name)
result = edit_request.execute()
edit_id = result['id']

apk_response = service.edits().apks().upload(
        editId=edit_id,
        packageName=package_name,
        media_body=apk_file).execute()

print('Version code %d has been uploaded but not yet committed' % apk_response['versionCode'])

if track:
    track_response = service.edits().tracks().update(
        editId=edit_id,
        track=track,
        packageName=package_name,
        body={u'track': track,
            u'releases': [{
            u'name': release_name,
            u'versionCodes': [str(apk_response['versionCode'])],
            u'status': u'completed',
        }]}).execute()

    print('Track %s is set with releases: %s' % (
        track_response['track'], str(track_response['releases'])))
else:
    print('No track specified')

commit_request = service.edits().commit(
        editId=edit_id, packageName=package_name).execute()

print('Edit "%s" has been committed' % commit_request['id'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "track" to the request body as well.

e.g.

```
body={u'track': track,
u'releases': [{
u'name': release_name,
u'versionCodes': [str(apk_response['versionCode'])],
u'status': u'completed',
...
```

This worked for me. You can check the expected request body structure here:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/tracks#resource

Comment: This was a recent change from Google Play API. Thanks for posting this--it fixed my broken upload step as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having similar problems publishing with Codemagic [Google Play publishing fails with "Track names in request path and request body must match"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655450/google-play-publishing-fails-with-track-names-in-request-path-and-request-body), looks like something might be wrong on Google's side

Answer (score 1):

I am also having similar issue, opened issue here.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/840

If all the folks can tag on this issue that would help.

I find myself in similar situation, it worked last week and now its broken...

Answer (score 1):

For other people who use java version of Android publisher, i had the same error.

maven artifact : google-api-services-androidpublisher

java error during publish :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.netfinca.mobile.publish.apk.PublisherHelperException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Track names in request path and request body must match.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Track names in request path and request body must match.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

To solve it, we must set the track attribute of the "com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.model.Track" object

The code will be like this :

```
Edit edit = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(...);
Track trackObject = new Track().setTrack(trackValue); // trackValue could be internal, alpha, ...
edit.tracks().update(androidPackage, editId, trackValue, trackObject );
```

In my case, it was missing this :

```
.setTrack(trackValue);
```