# Google Play publishing fails with "Track names in request path and request body must match"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api, codemagic

I'm using Codemagic to build and publish apks to Google Play's internal track, on March 10 it was working fine, but today I got this:

```
Publishing
35s



== Gathering artifacts ==

== Publishing artifacts ==

Publishing artifact app.apk
Publishing artifact app-prod-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
Publishing artifact app-prod-x86_64-release.apk
Publishing artifact app-prod-arm64-v8a-release.apk
Publishing artifact mapping.txt
Publishing app.apk, app-prod-armeabi-v7a-release.apk, app-prod-x86_64-release.apk, app-prod-arm64-v8a-release.apk to Google Play
Published app.apk to track internal
Published app-prod-armeabi-v7a-release.apk to track internal
Publishing proguard mapping mapping.txt to Google Play
Published app-prod-x86_64-release.apk to track internal
Publishing proguard mapping mapping.txt to Google Play
Published app-prod-arm64-v8a-release.apk to track internal
Publishing proguard mapping mapping.txt to Google Play
Google Play responded with: Track names in request path and request body must match.

Build failed :|


Publishing failed :|
Google Play responded with: Track names in request path and request body must match.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately there was an internal error in Codemagic. It has been resolved for now and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I used the PlayStorePublisher tool and today I started to receive the same error.
https://github.com/rocel/playstorepublisher
I think Google is doing some changes to the publish API.

Comment: that's also correct, we fixed it by sending track name in google play api request body